# MS Word mail merge: organise every nth record?

Tags: ms-word, mergefield, docx-mailmerge

The Excel file has seven records (rows). I would like to organise every three records together. Yet, the following code returns a calculation error.

{ IF { =MOD({MERGESEQ},3) = 0} "{ MERGESEQ }: { MERGEFIELD _record}" "" }

How can I fix the error? Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you have the = 0 inside the { = } field when it should be outside, like this:

```
{ IF { =MOD({MERGESEQ},3) } = 0 "{ MERGESEQ }: { MERGEFIELD _record}" "" }
```

Another thing that could cause a syntax error is the case where your Windows regional settings require you to use ";" instead of "," as a list separator (i.e. in that case you would need

```
{ IF { =MOD({MERGESEQ};3) } = 0 "{ MERGESEQ }: { MERGEFIELD _record}" "" }
```

Comment: Thank you! But another issue comes but it seems I couldn't insert a picture here. So I'd like to start a new question.